# How to display data in Gridview in Asp.Net Mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Normally in Asp.Net has a lot of example on how to display data in GridView Control. With Asp.Net Mvc 6, I want to display the data in GridView, in stead of table view in razor engine. I am trying to look for this GridView Control, but it does not exist in the razor control toolbox. Do some experts know how to retrieve data from sql server database to show in the GridView Control?

Comment: Razor doesn't have controls in the same way as Web Forms. You can use Razor syntax such as a `foreach` loop to build up your own HTML, or you can use [HTML helpers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and) to accomplish this. However, asking for a specific HTML helper recommendation would probably make your question off-topic since it's asking for tool recommendations.

Comment: @mason - if you know of a DataGrid Helper then please post it, that wouldn't be off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

You can try PagedList https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList, it's not to difficult to get setup and running.